# Laravel model cast performance

Tags: laravel

We are converting the timestamp in our table from UTC to user specific timezone. The UserStats table has millions of records.

Solution 1: Eloquent based

```
class UserStats extends Model
{

protected $table = 'user_stats';
protected $guarded = [];

protected $casts = [
    'time_stamp' => UserTimezoneCast::class,
];
}

class UserTimezoneCast implements CastsAttributes
{

public function get($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
{
    $userTimeZone = App::make('user_timezone');
    $appTimeZone = App::make('app_timezone');
    return Carbon::parse($value, $appTimeZone)->setTimezone($userTimeZone)->format('Y-m-d');
}

public function set($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
{
    return $value;
}
}
```

When we try to fetch the data for one month  using the below query then it returns data in around 12 seconds

```
UserStats::whereBetween("time_stamp", [$startDate, $endDate])->whereIn('user_id', $userIds)->get()
```

Solution 2:

```
UserStats::selectRaw("user_id, DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(time_stamp, '$appTimeZone', '$userTimeZone'),     
'%Y-%m-%d') as time_stamp_date , sum(total_time)")
->whereBetween("time_stamp", [$startDate, $endDate])->whereIn('user_id', $userIds)
->groupBy('user_id')
->get()
```

This query return result in 3 to 4 second.

Question: does the cast in model is that slow ?

```
$casts = [
    'time_stamp' => UserTimezoneCast::class,
];
```